# Python request - Submit a form that has javascript onsubmit

Tags: python, forms, python-requests, submit

I'm trying to use Python requests to get the results of this url [Target URL](https://www.cmfchile.cl/institucional/mercados/entidad.php?mercado=V&rut=61808000&tipoentidad=RVEMI&control=svs&pestania=25). As you could see, it updates on javascript when you push button "Consultar" (leaving fields empty), so post method is not working.

I'm trying this code right here:

```
import requests

URL = https://www.cmfchile.cl/institucional/mercados/entidad.php?mercado=V&rut=61808000&tipoentidad=RVEMI&control=svs&pestania=25

page = requests.post(URL, headers=headers)

print(page.text)
```

Does anyone know any other way or how I could solve this?

Comment: That is not valid python code.  Please post your real code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
import requests

url = "https://www.cmfchile.cl/institucional/mercados/entidad.php?mercado=V&rut=61808000&tipoentidad=RVEMI&control=svs&pestania=25"

payload='dd=%23%23%23&mm=%23%23%23&aa=%23%23%23&dd2=%23%23%23&mm2=%23%23%23&aa2=%23%23%23&dias=&entidad=AGUAS%2BANDINAS%2BS.A.&rut=61808000%2B&formulario=1'
headers = {
  'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:96.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/96.0',
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.text)
```

The process I followed was to:

1. Copy the request as cURL in Firefox:

[image: Copy request as cURL]

2. Import it into Postman:

[image: Import button]

[image: Paste cURL into Postman]
3. Export as Python code from Postman:

[[image: Export Python code]]
[image: Export Python code]